# Using a static table as a navigation property of a dynamic table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Okay so I've run into this unprecedented scenario in my asp.net core mvc application.  For context my application is a deck building/sharing website for a card game (similar to hearthpwn or icyveins).  I have a table "Card" that will remain unchanged until new cards are released to the game.  I also have a table "Deck" that will store user decks and require a relationship to the Card table.  Im learning mvc from the asp.net website tutorials and want to continue down the path of using entityframeworkcore for all my database interactions.  So, my class for Deck looks like this:

```
public class Deck
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DeckCard> DeckCards { get; set; }
}
```

I want Cards to be the navigation property for Deck.  I have no idea how to make this work using the methods provided in the tutorials.

number 1: using a dbinitializer and seeding test data to a database makes no sense while using a static table.  each Card row would require a DeckID property and this isnt practical because obviously each card is going to be used in more than one deck, or at least most of them would.  So logically speaking this method would require a dynamic Card table in which i would create a new existing Card row every time a card was used in a deck.  Obviously this isnt the correct solution.  I can make it work via using a string property on the deck model and appending the cardID and doing some magic that way but thats sloppy and not relational.  I need to be able to query against the navigation property of the Deck model..

Any insight or tips would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sorry if this question is convoluted but i hardly even know what to ask with my experience; im very new to relational databases and the asp.net framework.  Thanks in advance!

**EDIT : Wrote new data model class (DeckCard) to use for join table**

```
public class DeckCard()
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public int DeckID {get; set;}
    public int CardID {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest implementation would be to have a lookup table. Each Deck would have a Collection of DeckCards, which would have a DeckId and a CardId. Thus the different Users' Decks could point to the same Card and you wouldn't need a new Card per Deck, just a lookup saying that this Deck also has access to that Card.

Comment: I appreciate the input, I will definitely start googling how to do this with EF.

Comment: Using a lookup table would imply that I don't need a navigation property of Card type in the Deck model, right?

Comment: I think you'd still want a nav property. You would likely want to access the Deck's Cards like this:  var myCard = myDeck.DeckCards.Card.Where(x => x.CardId == targetCardId).Single(); or something like that.

Comment: Hey man I wrote a new model class for DeckCard and added a nav property to the Deck model (ICollection<DeckCard>).  I'm still so lost as to how to populate the collection property.  Is there someway I can post it back from the view?  I'm using javascript 'onclick' handlers to click on each card entity thats loaded into the (Deck/Create) view, should I be writing some C# code in the handler definition?

Comment: I'm reintroducing myself to OOP at the same time as I'm beginning to learn web development, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @j3ss, it would be tough to help you in the comments here. You should try some different things, look at some tutorials, and if they aren't helping, go ahead and ask some specific questions showing what you're trying to do that isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is an intermediary table.  You have the Deck table, the Card table, and a CardInDeck table.  The Deck table has a DeckID, the Card table has a CardID, and the CardInDeck table has both a CardID and a DeckID.

This way, you can link multiple cards to a deck.

Someone else will have to explain how to do that with EF, but that's what you want as far as table design.

Comment: I appreciate the input, I will definitely start googling how to do this with EF.